# NOOB to using DevC++ version 4.9.9.2 Please assist

Tags: c++

Good Evening I am new to C++ programming and I am using a compiler called DevC++ version 4.9.9.2. It worked when i wrote programs in the beginning, but is now giving me a lot of trouble. Every time I execute a syntax error does not come up, however the program still does not execute. What is the problem and please help as I spent hours on this already. What should  I do?

Comment: I know DevC++ is nice and lightweight but it's old and presumably the included version of gcc isn't that great, either. [Maybe it's time to join the winning team](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express)? C'mon... it's got great features such as "(a) More inviting start page"...

Comment: yeah the winning team, http://www.mingw.org/

Comment: @L7ColWinters Couldn't find an IDE in that team of yours.

Comment: @todda.speot.is Code::Blocks!

Comment: @todda.speot.is: Emacs, Code Blocks, Eclipse, Net Beans, IntelliJ IDEA... Not to mention that GNU tools, like Unix, is an IDE in itself.

Comment: @VladLazarenko None of those IDEs are part of mingw, unless you count the GNU toolchain as an *integrated* development environment.

Comment: oh hell I do! those using visual studio are just moaning.. often not even knowing about it, and some even defend it!

Comment: Everyone's focusing on the fact that you're using an ancient compiler/IDE (you are), but no one's actually tried to solve your problem. First step is editing your question to include the actual compilation error that you're receiving, and some sample code that you've tried to compile.

Comment: @CodyGray He says he doesn't get an error.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing DevC++ again. If still does not work try Code::Blocks or Eclipse IDE. Good luck and happy learning

Comment: i tried code::blocks but I don't know how to get the compiler to work...still what should I do

Comment: I believe i have both the MinGW and the code::blocks compiler installed the only thing is when i try to run the program in my command line using g++ Untitled1.cpp -o untitled1.exe it says Untitled.cpp is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file hmmmmmm idk know what to do from this point

Comment: @RicardoTheviscountMedley: You are using an Integrated Development Environment. One of the points of that is to not *have* to execute a command line to build stuff. If you're using Code::Blocks, you should be building *though* Code::Blocks.

Comment: In code::blocks just hit the the f9 key to compile and link your exe

Answer (score 0):

Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2 is from 2005. That's too ancient, don't use it. 
Instead, use the newest version available here (at the moment of writing, Dev-C++ 5.1.0.0 released 27 December 2011): http://orwellengine.blogspot.com/

Comment: believe i have both the MinGW and the code::blocks compiler installed the only thing is when i try to run the program in my command line using g++ Untitled1.cpp -o untitled1.exe it says Untitled.cpp is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file hmmmmmm idk know what to do from this point

Comment: (Terminology) Note that MinGW is a port of the GCC (GNU Compiler Collection) to Windows, and GCC includes g++, a C++ compiler. Both Dev-C++ & C::B are so-called integrated development environments (IDEs), which happen to integrate editing (and debugging, profiling, etc.) with whatever compiler you choose -- can be either g++ from MinGW GCC, or cl.exe from Microsoft Visual C++. Please remember the distinction between a compiler and an IDE, it can help to alleviate some confusion! Now, to your error message, could you provide the screenshot (or a text-dump) of accompanying messages for context?